# How to migrate list custom setting to custom meta data types

Tags: customsetting, custom-metadata

If you are thinking of using list custom setting ,consider using custom metadata types instead.

Here problems is how can i migrate the records of custom metadata types using packages or metadata API tools

Comment: Sets

In case, if you need to import data into Custom metadata type, you need to use Custom Metadata Loader. Refer Load or Update Records with the Custom Metadata Loader

Comment: But how i can approach through the packages ??

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Summer 17, you can create an install script that reads custom settings records and deploys custom metadata records based on them. Main gotcha there is that list custom settings names don't have to be valid identifiers, so you may need to process them to make acceptable custom metadata record DeveloperNames.

Note also that custom metadata records created by install scripts always have the subscriber org's namespace (or no namespace, if the subscriber org doesn't have one). That means that if these were *protected* custom settings, you should make sure your custom metadata type is protected, because simply protecting the records won't stop the subscriber org from seeing them.

Comment: An example of the copy code would be nice...